# Extract string slice with regex

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a column which looks like this:

| ProductName |
| --- |
| SQL Database Single Standard - S0 - DE West Central |
| SQL Database Single Standard - 10 DTU - DE West Central |
| SQL Database Single Standard - S0 |
| SQL Database Single Premium - P4 - DE West Central |
| SQL Database Single General Purpose - Compute Gen5 - 1 vCore - US East |

And I would like to extract part of the string to have a result like this:

| ProductName |
| --- |
| S0 |
| 10 |
| S0 |
| P4 |
| 1 vCore |

Is there any way to do RegEx with DAX and:

- Eliminate everything after the last `-`
- Take the part before the the last two `-` * `-`

Comment: Do you want a DAX or PQ solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerQuery**
Create a Custom Column with:

```
List.Reverse(Text.Split([ProductName], " - ")){1}
```

Split the string on `" - "`, reverse it, then take the 2nd one.

**DAX**
Create a Calculated Column with:

```
Column = 
  var p = SUBSTITUTE([ProductName], " - ", "|")
  return PATHITEMREVERSE(p, IF(PATHLENGTH(p) < 3, 1, 2), TEXT)
```

Comment: it says "List.Reverse is not a function" but I see the point. Thank you.